# How can you find the distance between zip codes in C# or SQL Server?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, wpf, zip

There must be a standard and efficient way to do so, since it's obviously a very widely used feature on many websites.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know that there is a "standard" way.

There may be existing services that do it, and there may be databases you can purchase or get for free that have usable data, but depending on your definition, this may not be easy to calculate.

Think about this: Your question could be interpreted as the shortest as-the-crow-flies distance between two points (cheating by using a point in a city that lies in that zip code), or it could be interpreted as the driving distance between the edge of two zip code boundaries.  The first calculation is fairly simple, but isn't 100% accurate.  The second is not a trivially easy problem.  Finding the shortest driving distance is one sub-problem, and finding the closest points at the edge of irregular boundaries is another sub-problem (or finding the nearest city/known coordinates of the person invoking the feature).

So, without any information as to the actual problem you are trying to solve, I can only assume you don't care how accurate your data is.  In that case, I suggest acquiring a database of coordinates of cities, which zip codes they lie in, and use the standard subtractions/square-root to determine the distance (pythagorean theorem).

If you do care how accurate your data is, I suggest you research to find an existing database or service that has more accurate information pre-calculated for you, or farmed to you.

Comment: Agree! What is distance? Define it first! Is it Euclidean distance (pythagoras, straight-line), is it driving distance based upon shortest path, or "fastest" path. Assuming this would be built-in functionality in SQL Server or .NET sounds pretty strange to me. It's typically an OR (operations Research e.q. econometrics) question. I assume there will be services for this, or databases with algorithms (I once used a third party component) but you don't get those for free usually...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Merlyn. I didn't consider there were so many factors. No, though, accuracy will not be extremely important (within miles is fine.)

Comment: BTW, straight-line distance from a point in the zip code is what I'm referring to. I'm looking into the solution provided by Arsen.

@Joep - Nowhere in my question would you find that I thought it was "included" in .NET or SQL Server. I only asked for the most standard practice. Consider being helpful next time.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a PHP script way back to calculate the distance between zip codes. Since then, through a lot of feedback from users, it has been modified so that the distance calculation is actually done with SQL queries as that was the most efficient way to do it.

You need a table that has zip codes and their lat/long values. There are free and commercial databases with this information available all over the web.

Take a look at [this PHP source code](https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-ZipCode-Class/blob/master/zipcode.php) and look at the `calcDistanceSql()` method. It should be simple enough to follow the query that is built and implement it in SQL Server.